# Prevent user from registering if username is taken

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So my script perfectly checks whether username is free or not but regardless of that when user submits all forms he is able to register. I need a way to prevent user from registering if username is taken. Here is the code:

index.php

```
$("#username").keyup(function(){
    var val=$("#username").val();
    $("#address").html("Your address will be askfolio.com/" + val);

    $("#freeu").html("<img src='css/ajax-loader.gif' style='margin-left:-75px;'>");
    if (val != ''){
        $.ajax({
            url:"s/ufree.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$("#username"),
            success:function(data){
                if (data == 1){
                    $("#freeu").html("<img src='css/accept.png' style='float:left;padding-right:65px;'>");
                    $("#reg-error").css("display","none");

                }else{
                    $("#freeu").html('');
                    $("#reg-error").css("display","block");
                    $("#reg-error").html('Username is already taken, try another.');
                    $("#username").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            }
        });

    }else {
        $("#freeu").html('');
    }


});
function Users_Registration() 
{
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var lastname=$("#lastname").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var remail = $("#remail").val();
    var rpass = $("#rpass").val();
    var day=$("#day").val();
    var month=$("#month").val();
    var year=$("#year").val();


    if(name == "")
    {
        $("#reg-error").css("display","block");
        $("#reg-error").html('Please enter your name in the required field.');
        $("#name").focus();
    }

    else if(lastname == "")
    {
        $("#reg-error").css("display","block");
        $("#reg-error").html(' Please enter your Last Name in the required field.');
        $("#lastname").focus();
    }
    else if(username == ""){
        $("#reg-error").css("display","block");
        $("#reg-error").html('Please enter your desired username to proceed.');
        $("#username").focus();
    }
    else if(remail == "")
    {
        $("#reg-error").css("display","block");
        $("#reg-error").html('Please enter your email address to proceed.');
        $("#remail").focus();
    }
    else if(reg.test(remail) == false)
    {
        $("#reg-error").css("display","block");
        $("#reg-error").html('Please enter a valid email address to proceed.');
        $("#remail").focus();
    }else if (rpass == "") {
        $("#reg-error").css("display","block");
        $("#reg-error").html('Please enter a valid password to proceed.');
        $("#rpass").focus();
    }
    else if (day == ""){
        $("#reg-error").css("display","block");
        $("#reg-error").html('Please select a day to proceed.');
        $("#day").focus();

    }else if (month == "") {
        $("#reg-error").css("display","block");
        $("#reg-error").html('Please select a month to proceed.');
        $("#month").focus();
    }else if (year == "") {
        $("#reg-error").css("display","block");
        $("#reg-error").html('Please select a year to proceed.');
        $("#year").focus();
    }
    else
    {
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&lastname='+ lastname + '&username='+ username + '&rpass='+ rpass + '&remail='+ remail + '&year=' + year + '&month=' + month + '&day=' + day  +'&page=signup';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() 
            {
                $("#reg-error").html('<br clear="all"><div style="padding-left:115px;"><font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:black;">Please wait</font> <img src="images/loadings.gif" alt="Loading...." align="absmiddle" title="Loading...."/></div><br clear="all">');
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                $("#reg-error").html("Loading");
                var username="<?php echo $loguser; ?>";
                window.location=username;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ufree.php

```
<?php

include "db.php";

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
        echo "1";
    }else {
        echo "<div style='padding-top:4px;'>username is taken</div>";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Not only can the user register, he can also get the usernames on passwords of other members. You have a SQL injection vulnerability on your code. Learn to escape your user input before adding them to your query. Also the mysql_* functions are deprecated. update to mysqli. In your users table set the username field to UNIQUE

Comment: i've added mysql_real_escape string but that function adds quoation next to slash in my db...anyways i need help on preventing double usernames and i will move to mysqli instead

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the SQL Injection vulnerability that you have in your sql queries, your approach to username check is somewhat redundant. By checking the username upon every character input you add extra load to the browser and to your server.

I suggest you combine the two processes in one step meaning you do the username check and register in the same place. In your `Register.php` file check the username availability right before the registration and if the username is taken display a proper message and if not do the registration.

Comment: Agree -- and you probably don't want to hear this -- but you can't solely rely on javascript to validate all your forms. This means validating all data server-side before inserting in the database, which is a pain in the butt but necessary if you really don't want any bad data to slip through. Work on better code organization and remember to stay DRY: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 0):

Goes without saying but regardless of the javascript validation, your server still needs to be checking that the username is available at point of registering, since anyone can disable or manipulate the javascript.

Also as Hamed states, your php code is highly vulnerable.  At the very least, you should use the following prior to using it in your sql:

`$username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST[ 'username' ] );`

That said, for usability, what you need to do is add an onsubmit function to your form, which checks if the username is valid or not prior to submitting. (summarised your code for simplicity)

```
var validUser = false;

$("#username").keyup(function(){

    var val=$("#username").val();

    validUser = false;

    if (val != ''){
        $.ajax({
            url:"s/ufree.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:val,
            success:function(data){
                if (data == 1){
                    validUser = true;
                }else{
                    $("#username").focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

}else {
$("#freeu").html('');
}

function formsubmit()
{
    if( !validUser )
    {
        alert( 'Username is already taken, try another' );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then in your form:

```
<form action="whatever" onsubmit="return formsubmit();">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once of my favorite jQuery plugin is the validation eng.

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

It has very nice validation for doing just what you are looking for. It does all kinds of fields including inline ajax for username check. If the response from ajax call is not true, then the form won't submit. I use it for my signup forms. Once the user goes to the next field it validates, if it doesn't pass i.e. the username is not available, it will say username not available in red. The form won't submit.

It's not hard to setup. Here is a demo of the ajax. Note it won't actually validate on this demo site but it's an example. You can see how it won't submit though if it's blank or not validated. It's very customizable.

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoAjaxSubmitPHP.html

Oh course take care of any mysql security issues and check to make sure dupes can't be entered into the database as well.